# How do I access cookies in a helper spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I can't figure out how to test that a cookie has been set when testing my helper method.

Hypothetical helper method:

```
def my_helper(k,v)
    cookies[k] = v
end
```

Test:

```
it 'should set cookies' do  
  helper.my_helper("foo", "bar")
  helper.cookies["foo"].should == "bar" #nil
  helper.response.cookies["foo"].should == "bar" #nil
end
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475989/rspec-setting-cookies-in-a-helper-test

here, always do your homework!

Comment: I saw that post, as the OP mentions, he's still not sure how to _get_ cookies.

Comment: According to the rspec docs `response.cookies["foo"]` should work but I'm on rails 3.2 and rspec 2.8 and it does not work for me. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/cookies. As far as I can tell there's something strange going on between rspec, rails integration tests, and rack which makes this hard to figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting a simple rspec mock for the CookieJar works, if you're willing to:

```
helper.stubs(:cookies => cookies = mock)
cookies.expects(:[]=).with('foo', 'bar')
helper.my_helper('foo', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm on rails 3.2 and rspec 2.8. Despite what the [rspec docs](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/cookies) says the following works for me in a **request** spec (ie. integration test).

```
it 'should set cookies' do  
  cookies['foo'] = 'bar'
  visit "/"
  cookies['foo'].should == 'bar'
end
```

Comment: Yup, I've definitely checked cookies in standard request specs.

Comment: @MattBaker Which version of rails and rspec you're using?

Comment: @MattBaker also here an article about how someone debugged their way through using cookies in rspec. It might help you figure out how to troubleshoot this whole thing. http://dobbse.net/thinair/2011/12/capybara-racktest-rspec-cookies-2of2.html

Comment: We're on rails 3.1.4 and rspec 2.8. Maybe I'll take a shot at upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

request the cookie through

```
 helper.request.cookies[:awesome] = "something"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Remember, I'm trying to _get_ the cookie, not set it.