# strange cookie behavior in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am trying to work through the rails tutorial,  and ran into a problem.
In the process of debugging it I ran into this strange behavior, which I think is related to my problem.

```
>rails console
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.16)
irb(main):001:0> app.cookies['foo'] = 'bar'
=> "bar"
irb(main):002:0> app.cookies['remember_token'] = 'foobar'
=> "foobar"
irb(main):003:0> app.cookies['foo']
=> "bar"
irb(main):004:0> app.cookies['remember_token']
=> "foobar"
irb(main):005:0> app.put app.root_url
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1
=> 200
irb(main):006:0> app.cookies['foo']
=> "bar"
irb(main):007:0> app.cookies['remember_token']
=> ""
```

Notice how cookies['foo'] remains set to 'bar' after a put, but cookies['remember_token'] gets set to ""

Can anyone explain what might be going on here?
I do have a column "remember_token" in the model,  but I don't see how that should come into play.

Here is the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  validates :name, presence: true, 
                   length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true,
                       length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true                     
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  before_save :create_remember_token


    private

    def create_remember_token
      puts "in create remember_token"  #added for debug
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      puts remember_token   #added for debug
    end

end
```

and here is the database :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20140111165943) do

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_token"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["remember_token"], :name => "index_users_on_remember_token"

end
```

My original question was related to test failures , and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210077/why-does-a-cookie-set-in-a-test-not-show-up-in-a-controller)

**Update:  Found source of this strange behavior**

As I began to get together the code to show the full controller (as requested in the comment), it became clear that this was going to be the source of my problem.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper

  # Force signout to prevent CSRF attacks
  def handle_unverified_request
    sign_out
    super
  end


end
```

and here is the sign_out method (in my sessions_helper)

```
def sign_out
    puts "in sign out"
    cookies.delete :remember_token
    self.current_user = nil
  end
```

I added a puts in the sign_out method and saw that it was called as soon as a did a put (but not a get).  Now I have to back to the tutorial and see what I must have done wrong.

Comment: Please show full controller including sign in method

Comment: @BillyChan thanks, that request was all I needed to figure it out.  First thing I did was to open up the ApplicationController and found the above code (updated in my question)

Comment: nPn, nice you figured it out by yourself! Controller is the only possible place to make such changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was a result of having protect_from_forgery on and a sign_out method in handle_unverified_request.
See the update at the end of the question for the details